# Batch file only runs after opening .csv file

Tags: excel, batch-file

I'm having a bit of a strange problem. I got a .csv file that I want to process. The script works fine and I didn't have any problems testing with a small .csv file but when I try to run the batch on the original .csv (around 100k lines, 7MB) for some reason the script only runs AFTER I open the file in Excel.

The script completes just fine apart from not running without opening Excel so I'm not really sure what is going on. Especially since it does run automatically with a smaller file.

```
setlocal
set "file=test2.csv"
set "fileout=output.csv"

set /p "var="<"%file%" >nul

>"%fileout%" echo.%var%,test_column

for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('type "%file%"') do (
>>%fileout% echo.%%a,test_value
)
```

Comment: I don't see any problems with your code. Opening Excel has nothing to do with your script.

Comment: I know, that is why I don't understand why the script won't run until I start Excel. It only happens with a "large" (100k lines) file. On smaller files it does run automatically without starting Excel.

Comment: The batch file will run extremely slow with 100K lines because you keep opening and closing the file.  Just open and close the file once. `(for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('type "%file%"') do echo.%%a,test_value)>>%fileout%`

Comment: Thanks but for whatever reason that still doesn't run automatically. And with that script it also doesn't work when I open Excel because it complains about the process already being in use.

The problem is that for whatever reason the large .csv isn't processed while a smaller one is.

Comment: The updated code I gave you puts a file lock on the output file.  Your existing code would not stop Excel from opening the output file because it is constantly opening and closing the file.  So whatever had been written to the file could be opened by Excel.  You also have to understand that the `FOR` command reads the entire file before it starts processing the output.  It could very well take 10 to 20 minutes for it to read the file and then output the file.  Stop focusing on Excel.  It has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: I created a 100K line file that was 7.1 MB.  I then ran it through my code and it took almost 5 minutes for it to create the output file.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to read the file directly instead of reading the output from the `TYPE` command.  Also enclose all your code so that it keep the file open for writing.

```
@echo off
set "file=input.csv"
set "fileout=output.csv"

set /p "var="<"%file%"

(
echo.%var%,test_column
for /f "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%a in ("%file%") do echo.%%a,test_value
)>"%fileout%"
```

Comment: Thanks. That is much faster, but it adds a new line and a copy of the original line but with C:/path in front. I tried echo | set /p but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @sjaak, your comment isn't making any sense to me.  My code will not output the drive letter or path to the output.

Comment: I don't know why but for every original line that script adds 1 newline and a copy of the original line but the first column contains C:/path echo before the original value.

Comment: that's because of a missing `@echo off`, so the command repetition strikes back.